# Symfony request with json for postman

Tags: json, symfony

I have my CRUD but I need to do a POST request with postman. I've been reading some posts but I don't really understand how it works.

My routing for that:

```
jugador_create:
path:     /{_format}
defaults: { _controller: "FutbolBundle:Jugador:new", _format: html }
requirements: { _method: post, _format: html|xml|json }
```

My controller is this:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Jugador();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('jugador_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }}

    return $this->render('FutbolBundle:Jugador:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

How do I do it so in postman I can do a JSON post and it creates it? I think I need to do a switch with Json, xml and default case but I don't really understand how to do the Json part.

Thank you so much.

Also, in my index I already did the switch with Json and xml but it's pretty different to a GET than a POST.

```
public function indexAction(Request $request){
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $serializer = new Serializer(array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()),array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()));
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('FutbolBundle:Jugador')->findAll();

    switch ($request->getRequestFormat()){
        case "json":
            $response=new Response();
            $response->setContent($serializer->serialize($entities,'json'));
            return $response;
        break;
        case "xml":
            $response=new Response();
            $response->setContent($serializer->serialize($entities,'xml'));
            return $response;

        break;
        default:
            return $this->render('FutbolBundle:Jugador:index.html.twig', array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    ));
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The code looks like you have a form, but your message sounds like you are trying to make an API endpoint? Are you trying to turn your POST data into JSON so the endpoint can handle it?  Why do you need the "format" part?

Comment: The form is for the html. The format is for the call, when I call the url I have to put json or xml, that's why I will do a switch to call the format I want. What I want to do is, in postman, do a post request with json, but I guess I can't do it with the controller I have right now. I'm so sorry because english isn't my main language and I'm having a hard time trying to explain, thank you.

Comment: You can POST to the URL however you want. You just need to decide what to do with the data. You should set up a mapper than maps the JSON to your Entity. You can use the Request Stack and get access to your data like this `$this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('FIELD');` or just dump the whole request and see what you have to use. `dump($request->request->all())`

Comment: Also you don't need this in your indexAction `$request = $this->getRequest();` - you are already passing in the request

Comment: I see, will try to do and see if I can get it, I'm pretty new with php and this whole thing so it's a bit difficult for me. Thank you so much! And thank you for the info about the request, didn't knew! My teacher told me to do that but it makes sense. Again, thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just in case anyone needs help, I actually did it pretty simple using sets and the entity of Symfony.

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(),true);
$entity->setNom($data["nom"]);
$entity->setEquip($data["equip"]);
... (more sets if you need them)
```

and this for inserting it into the data base.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Why? my solution is better than yours, optimizes the code better. Your are free to choose what ever you want but your code is the same as mine with some downgrades. Your are doing the setting manually, you should let the form handle the setting.

Answer (score 2):

My sugestion is as follow:

> Implemet a format listener to avoid repeating your code in all controllers

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if ('json' === $request->getContentType() && $request->getContent()) {
           $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true); 
           $request->request->replace($data);
        }       
    }
```

After that your controller should not change because you already transformed the data from json to regular posted data. You can do the same with the xml format or what ever format you want but html.

> Specify the headers in postman
>    At Headers options below the method/url just add the Content-type header as follow.

```
Content-type(key) application/json (value)
Content-type(key) application/xml (value)
```

That should work

Hope it helps.

PD: Si no entiendes todo lo que he escrito hazmelo saber.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Lo entendí, y de hecho he visto que prácticamente es lo que hice pero sí, me ahorra mucho hacerlo en uno sólo. Mi único problema ahora, pero nada que ver con esto, es que tengo una fecha de nacimiento y no me la da por válida, pero creo que es el tipo de valor, datetime, de ahí que me de error.